# What's this obscure Sci-Fi book with sentient monkeys that 'mind meld with their tails'

Tags: story-identification, novel

Involves a group of upright 'evolved'/human like monkeys who seem to...
 1. Erroneously think they're human as humans have disappeared from Earth
 2. Have the ability to share souls or memories or something very intimate through their tails alone.

Story is set in distant future where earth is shared by 5 sentient races or so. Wasp like baddies who are trying to take over everything, dinosaur like overlords who hibernate for millions of years at a time and re-emerged while humans were still kicking about (I distinctly remember them having suicide machines). There were also a sentient species of plant, and after that I'm much more fuzzy, maybe some kind of robot or a fish....I don't know.

Comment: 'with' their tails, or *'using'* their tails?

Comment: I remembered chunks of the work, once I saw your question, but not enough to identify it.  Glad someone else found it, I was drawing a blank.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68085/furry-underground-race-with-sleeping-human-instructor-emerging-into-primitive-wo

Answer (score 5):

This is the [New Springtime](https://www.goodreads.com/series/58615-new-springtime) series, by Robert Silverberg:

1. [*At Winter's End*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/449320.At_Winter_s_End) (1988)

   [image: *At Winter's End*]
2. [*The New Springtime*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1833109.The_New_Springtime) (1991)

   [image: *The New Springtime*]

The setting, the simian People, and the other intelligent species are as you've described.

More information:

- [Furry underground race with sleeping human instructor emerging into primitive world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68085/furry-underground-race-with-sleeping-human-instructor-emerging-into-primitive-wo/68092#68092)